# Can we change the auto-generated "possible duplicate of..." to start with an uppercase?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, comments

After flagging a question for being a duplicate, an auto-generated comment reading

> possible duplicate of [original]

signed by ourselves is posted. For grammatical correctness, they should start with an uppercase

> Possible duplicate of [original]

I am aware that the comment is editable, but we treat comments as sentences and use uppercase in our "handwritten" comments, so there is no reason this shouldn't be the same.

I'm sure this is easy to change as the string is predefined somewhere.

Answer (score -8):

This is not a complete sentence.  This is a sentence fragment, and as such it *shouldn't* be capitalized.  It would be grammatically *incorrect* to capitalize it.

Comments, by design, do not need to be complete sentences.  They can be, but they can also not be.  They are intended to be short and informal.